# setTimeout и clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

При наведении на `div` c меню, фон вокруг затемняется, но если проводить так много раз, *mouseenter* & *mouseleave* из дива, начинает моргать. Решил установить `setTimeout`, получилось так:

```
$(".subcat > ul").hover(function(){
    var time_id = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 15 });
        $(".subcat_overlay").fadeIn();
    }, 1000);       
}, function(){
        $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 1 });
        $(".subcat_overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

Проблема сейчас в том, что нужна переменная, очищающая время, `clearTimeout(time_id);` Но куда её воткнуть, я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Можно сделать переменную `time_id` глобальной (вынести за пределы функции), после чего спокойно делать `clearTimeout(time_id);` перед `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

Как подсказал @Regent, Вам следует вынести ссылку на таймер в глобальное пространство, чтобы можно было обращаться к нему после окончания блока кода. А перед созданием нового таймера проверяйте наличие ранее созданных экземпляров – в этом случае удаляйте их.

```
var time_id = null;

$(".subcat > ul").hover(function(){
    if (time_id) {
        clearTimeout(time_id);
    }
    // убран var – иначе будет создаваться локальная переменная 
    time_id = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 15 });
        $(".subcat_overlay").fadeIn();
    }, 1000);       
}, function() {
        $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 1 });
        $(".subcat_overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Fade-функциии ставятся в очередь, не прервывая предыдущих.
Решение - stop

```
$(".subcat_overlay").stop().fadeIn()
$(".subcat_overlay").stop().fadeOut()
```

Либо вообще без таймаутов

```
$(".subcat_overlay").stop().fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете написать в стиле

```
.subcat_overlay{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.subcat_overlay_hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

И в JS

```
$(".subcat > ul").hover(function(){
    $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 15 });
    $(".subcat_overlay").addClass('.subcat_overlay_hover');       
}, function(){
    $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 1 });
    $(".subcat_overlay").removeClass('.subcat_overlay_hover');
});
```

Или же так (не уверен, что будет работать. Сделал увидев комментарий)

```
var time_id;
$(".subcat > ul").hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(time_id);
    time_id = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 15 });
        $(".subcat_overlay").fadeIn();
    }, 1000);       
}, function(){
    $(".subcat").css({ zIndex: 1 });
    $(".subcat_overlay").fadeOut();
});
```